# Python function does not return reuslt when called upon, no output. What am I doing wrong

Tags: python, function, return

I am new to python with limited knowledge in programming.
I was trying to use the def function to make an exponent calculator.
I give it a number and a second as the exponent i.e.: number ^ exponent. When I call for my function it does not return the result:

```
def power_to(base, power):
   return base ** power

base = int(input("insert base number here: "))       
power = int(input("insert power number here: "))
power_to(base, power)
```

here is the output of my code :

````
   insert power number here: 3
   Process finished with exit code 0```
````

Comment: You need to print the `power_to` output.

Comment: `print(power_to(2,3))--->8`

Comment: What does it imply if I call for my function without "print" ?

Comment: It worked but to my understanding if I type ```return``` in my function I do not have to use ```print```, am I wrong?

Comment: You are returning something from your function, you should either catch it in a variable and then later print the variable or directly print the output of your function as mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

You must print the output of **power_to** function

```
def power_to(base, power):
   return base ** power

base = int(input("insert base number here: "))       
power = int(input("insert power number here: "))
print(power_to(base, power))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your file you can add

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

statement and call your function from there, then print the result.

```
 def power_to(base, power):
    return base ** power


if __name__ == '__main__':
    base = int(input("insert base number here: "))
    power = int(input("insert power number here: "))

    result = power_to(base, power)
    print(result)
```